# Redis first time replication issue

Tags: redis

We are getting error "I/O error trying to sync with MASTER: connection lost" on the Slave while the first time replication.

Replication works properly when Master and Slave are in the same data centre but it fails when Master and Slave are located in different data centres. Our dump size is approx 10 GB.

We have already increased the Slave output buffer limit from 256MB upto 4GB step by step.

We want to keep two slaves in a different data centre for DR setup but both are  getting failed while the first time replication.

Slave logs

```
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.060 * Ready to accept connections
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.062 * Connecting to MASTER 172.26.62.27:6379
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.062 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.087 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.111 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.160 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.778 * Full resync from master: 81e9ab082195703215a30afd1fcdfda72b6b830c:321635678848
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:10:31.490 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 9813076238 bytes from master
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:31:29.700 # I/O error trying to sync with MASTER: connection lost
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:31:30.306 * Connecting to MASTER 172.26.62.27:6379
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:31:30.306 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:31:30.328 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:31:30.350 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:31:30.392 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:31:31.035 * Full resync from master: 81e9ab082195703215a30afd1fcdfda72b6b830c:322217209898
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 11:36:29.810 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync: receiving 9834183845 bytes from master
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 12:03:33.449 # I/O error trying to sync with MASTER: connection lost
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 12:03:34.185 * Connecting to MASTER 172.26.62.27:6379
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 12:03:34.185 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 12:03:34.215 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 12:03:34.246 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 12:03:34.307 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 12:03:34.968 * Full resync from master: 81e9ab082195703215a30afd1fcdfda72b6b830c:322492811258
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 12:04:29.032 # User requested shutdown...
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 12:04:29.032 * Removing the pid file.
128348:S 11 Jul 2019 12:04:29.032 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
```

Master logs.

```
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.171 * Replica 172.24.113.21:6379 asks for synchronization
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.171 * Full resync requested by replica 172.24.113.21:6379
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.171 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:05:30.765 * Background saving started by pid 6205
6205:C 11 Jul 2019 11:10:30.098 * DB saved on disk
6205:C 11 Jul 2019 11:10:30.632 * RDB: 369 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:10:31.479 * Background saving terminated with success
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:31:29.060 # Client id=167500710 addr=172.24.113.21:56053 fd=1359 name= age=1559 idle=1559 flags=S db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=1117 oll=9206 omem=581807888 events=rw cmd=psync scheduled to be closed ASAP for overcoming of output buffer limits.
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:31:29.061 # Connection with replica 172.24.113.21:6379 lost.
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:31:30.404 * Replica 172.24.113.21:6379 asks for synchronization
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:31:30.405 * Full resync requested by replica 172.24.113.21:6379
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:31:30.405 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:31:31.025 * Background saving started by pid 12360
12360:C 11 Jul 2019 11:36:28.482 * DB saved on disk
12360:C 11 Jul 2019 11:36:29.006 * RDB: 416 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 11:36:29.801 * Background saving terminated with success
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 12:03:33.029 # Client id=167693932 addr=172.24.113.21:12971 fd=1339 name= age=1923 idle=1923 flags=S db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=2862 oll=9878 omem=275934736 events=rw cmd=psync scheduled to be closed ASAP for overcoming of output buffer limits.
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 12:03:33.029 # Connection with replica 172.24.113.21:6379 lost.
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 12:03:34.325 * Replica 172.24.113.21:6379 asks for synchronization
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 12:03:34.325 * Full resync requested by replica 172.24.113.21:6379
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 12:03:34.325 * Starting BGSAVE for SYNC with target: disk
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 12:03:34.956 * Background saving started by pid 19777
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 12:04:29.052 # Connection with replica 172.24.113.21:6379 lost.
19777:C 11 Jul 2019 12:08:27.148 * DB saved on disk
19777:C 11 Jul 2019 12:08:27.670 * RDB: 457 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
128706:M 11 Jul 2019 12:08:28.529 * Background saving terminated with success
```

Comment: very interesting. Is it possible to run tcpdump to further investigate what's happening with the connection at TCP level?

Comment: i have capture tcpdump but its too large.Can't paste here.

Comment: We only need a fraction where slave <-> master connection is established and dropped to see what happened and which part actually dropped the connection

Answer (score 0):

In my case, increase `repl-backlog-size` parameter solved the problem!

```bash
redis-cli config set repl-backlog-size 1gb;
redis-cli config get repl-backlog-size;
sed -i 's/^# repl-backlog-size 1mb/repl-backlog-size 1gb/' /etc/redis/redis.conf; 
cat /etc/redis/redis.conf | grep repl-bac;
```